# Is there a way to disable Safari CSP (Content Security Policy) check?

Tags: macos, safari, security

Seems like Safari has a very strong restriction on Content Security Policy (CSP).

For example, on GitHub, most of the userscripts and extensions don't work because of it.

I get errors such as this from the console:

`[Error] Refused to execute a script because its hash, its nonce, or 'unsafe-inline' does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy. (pulls, line 0)`

How do I stop CSP check in Safari?